# Emails not being sent from CP after 2.6 update

Tags: email, smtp

Site is using Sendgrid (Smtp) to send newsletters via the Communicate Tab or Firemail and also using  Freeform for form notifications.

Since the 2.6 upgrade none of these work: Freeform is storing the form submissions in ths CP but no mails being sent. Communicate tab not working - error below - and notifications like 'lost password' not being sent either. These are the errors in Communicate tab:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to send email at this time.

The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

This is in a screen pop-up/overlay which obscures another error beneath:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1884
```

Not sure if this is an EE bug - tend to think it is - anyone else had issues with this?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question specifically, but I created the add-on Postmaster which is all about email. I have been working with 2.6 and can report there aren't any email issues I have come across, but code you posted doesn't really indicate there is a bug in the code, but rather the connection to SendGrid failed. I can't help you with a fix other than I don't think it's an EE 2.6 bug (although it could be, just making an educated guess).

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar problem after updating to EE 2.6.1. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to resolve it?